# Do we need to initialize an array?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Today as I read the [PrimeNg's](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/) source code, noticed one thing. The author of one utils class ([ObjectUtils](https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/utils/objectutils.ts)) in some cases initialized the arrays, but in other ones not.

**Example 1** from source code:

```
public static generateSelectItems(val: any[], field: string): SelectItem[] {
    let selectItems: SelectItem[];
    if(val && val.length) {
        selectItems = [];
        for(let item of val) {
            selectItems.push({label: this.resolveFieldData(item, field), value: item});
        }
    }

    return selectItems;
}
```

**Example 2** from source code:

```
public static filter(value: any[], fields: any[], filterValue: string) {
    let filteredItems: any[] = [];
    let filterText = this.removeAccents(filterValue).toLowerCase();

    if(value) {
        for(let item of value) {
            for(let field of fields) {
                let fieldValue = this.removeAccents(String(this.resolveFieldData(item, field))).toLowerCase();
                if(fieldValue.indexOf(filterText) > -1) {
                    filteredItems.push(item);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return filteredItems;
}
```

In second example he initialized the array `filteredItems`, but in first one does not (`selectItems` array). I'm wondering why he did so and if there is any best practices regarding this.

Comment: You should tag it with `typescript` and not with `javascript`.

Comment: @Xatenev - I *think* the consensus is that it's okay to tag TypeScript questions with [tag:javascript] since often they turn out to be about JavaScript, not TypeScript. (But definitely should be tagged [tag:typescript] whether tagged [tag:javascript] or not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
let selectItems: SelectItem[];
```

declares a variable, but does not create an array. (It doesn't initialize the variable with anything.) Later, the array is created using `[]`, here:

```
selectItems = [];
// -----------^^
```

...and then assigned to the variable.

This line:

```
let filteredItems: any[] = [];
```

...combines those two steps by providing a variable initializer.

The key thing to understand is that `selectItems` in the first example doesn't contain *anything*, at all, until it has something assigned to it. So it isn't that the programmer "hasn't initialized the *array*," it's that he/she hasn't initialized the *variable*.

You don't have to initialize a variable when declaring it. Both `let` and `var` declarations without an initializer initialize the variable to `undefined` (at different times, but that's not important here). (You *do* need to initialize a constant declared with `const` when declaring it, since you can't assign to it afterward.)

---

In a comment you asked:

> But when this `if(val && val.length)` fails in first example, then the function will return `undefined`. Won't be better if it returns let say an empty array?

That depends purely on what the programmer wants to have happen when `val` is falsy or has a falsy `length`. I'm sure there are use cases for returning `undefined` and for returning an empty array.

You may be wondering, though, about returning `undefined` when the type annotation on the function says it returns `SelectItem[]`. Remember that by default, `null` and `undefined` are effectively members of every type. You can turn that off with the `strictNullChecks` option, which is [documented](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) as:

> In strict `null` checking mode, the `null` and `undefined` values are not in the domain of every type and are only assignable to themselves and `any` (the one exception being that `undefined` is also assignable to `void`).

`strictNullChecks` would indeed have made that function an error. Compare this code:

```
function foo(bar: boolean) : Date {
    let x : Date;

    if (bar) {
        x = new Date();
    }

    return x;
}
foo(Math.random() < 0.5);
```

Try it [in the playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20foo(bar%3A%20boolean)%20%3A%20Date%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20x%20%3A%20Date%3B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20if%20(bar)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%20%3D%20new%20Date()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%0A%20%20%20%20return%20x%3B%0A%7D%0Afoo(Math.random()%20%3C%200.5)%3B) using the Options button to enable/disable 
`strictNullChecks`: TypeScript flags an error when it's enabled.

Comment: But when this `if(val && val.length)` fails in first example, then the function will return `undefined`. Won't be better if it returns let say an empty array?

Comment: @Gabriel That's perhaps exactly the author's intention.

Comment: @Gabriel - That depends purely on what the programmer wants to have happen when `val` is falsy or has a falsy `length`. I've added to the end of the answer to address that and why it isn't (or is) a problem for a function declared as returning `SelectItem[]`. (And to fix a silly mistake I made elsewhere in the answer.)